# EC2 userdata codecommit clone fails

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, aws-codecommit

I'm starting an ec2 instance from the userdata and I need to clone a repo with my ansible playbooks but it fails to clone. See details below. Can anyone help me figure this out. when I ssh to the instance after bootstrap, then clone works but not while bootstrapping.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -x

exec > >(tee /var/log/user-data.log|logger -t user-data -s 2>/dev/console) 2>&1

cd /home/ec2-user

mkdir -p .ssh
ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa -f /home/ec2-user/.ssh/codecommit -q -N ""

KEY_ID=`aws iam  upload-ssh-public-key --user-name ${user_id} --ssh-public-key-body "$(cat /home/ec2-user/.ssh/codecommit.pub)" \
  --query 'SSHPublicKey.SSHPublicKeyId' --output text`

echo -e "
Host git-codecommit.*.amazonaws.com
  User $KEY_ID
  IdentityFile /home/ec2-user/.ssh/codecommit
" >> /home/ec2-user/.ssh/config

ssh-keyscan -t rsa git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com >> /home/ec2-user/.ssh/known_hosts

  sudo chown -R ec2-user:ec2-user /home/ec2-user/.ssh
sudo chmod 700 /home/ec2-user/.ssh
sudo chmod 644 /home/ec2-user/.ssh/*
sudo chmod 600 /home/ec2-user/.ssh/codecommit*

eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"

export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v -F /home/ec2-user/.ssh/config -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no"
export GIT_TRACE_PACKET=true
export GIT_TRACE=2
export GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1

**sleep 60s**
git clone ssh://git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/ansible
```

Comment: Problem has been solved - A sleep of 60s before the clone fixed the issues

Comment: As you were able to solve the problem yourself, you can consider answering your own question (and even accepting your answer), to make it easier for others facing the same issue to find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a sleep of 60 seconds before the git clone command did the trick. It seems like SSH Key uploads take a bit of time before becoming active.

```
sleep 60s
git clone ssh://git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/ansible
```

OR

```
for i in {1..30}; do
  git clone ssh://git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/ansible      
  [ $? == 0 ] && break || sleep 2s; echo "keep trying ..."
done
```